# Access resources from resx in a form from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource, resx

So I have a windows forms dll.  There is a MainForm class which creates a ComponentResourceManager and accesses image resource stored in a resx for that form.  If I instantiate that class directly everything is happy.

If I add a new class to the same namespace (I just added it to the same .cs file as the MainForm class actually) and I try to access those image resources the same way I get an error about that resource not existing for the given culture.  Checking the current thread culture (and UI culture) they're the same for both.

Is there some extra hoop I need to jump thru to get access to a form's resources from another class?

Example code

```
namespace myNamespace
{
  public class extraClass
  {
    public extraClass()
    {
      System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(myForm));
      System.Drawing.Image img = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("StatusButton.Image")));
      MessageBox.Show(img.ToString());
    }
  }
  public class myForm : Form
  {
    public myForm()
    {
      System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(myForm));
      System.Drawing.Image img = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("StatusButton.Image")));
      MessageBox.Show(img.ToString());
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

In this example instantiating myForm would be happy but extraClass is not and fails with an error about not being able to find the resource in the given culture & did I make sure that the resource is embedded (it is).

Comment: Crazier and crazier.  So I was lazy and added my new class, extraClass, to the same cs file as myForm.  Turns out that having extraClass present, even if I strip it down to an empty class with an empty constructor, causes the main myForm to have the same error where it can't locate resources.  I'll be experimenting with moving extraClass around or to another file.  Maybe its because I'm using this dll from Python and the python clr bridge does nutty things?

Answer (score 0):

add the file to resource of the project. create an instance of the class named myForm  in the class named extraClass.

Comment: Right, so making it a project level resource would work.  But it should work to leave the resource in the Form.  In general don't want to have to make all resources into project level resources.  In particular I'm looking to do some odd stuff where I actually launch myForm from extraClass on a new thread which is totally fine except the resource access stuff is causing problems.  The fix so far has been to re-order the classes which is totally wacko since that shouldnt matter at all.